Where did "sprocket" sprout from?
Sprocket originally referred to a carpenter's tool, but its usual meaning now is a toothed wheel that drives a chain or gear.
Etymonline says 'of obscure origin':

1530s, originally a carpenters' word for a triangular piece of timber used in framing, of obscure origin. The meaning "one of the projections from the rim of a wheel that engage the links of a chain" is attested by 1750.

The OED says 'origin unknown' without adding anything else.
Where did the word 'sprocket' originate from? The word doesn't suggest triangularity based on its original meaning, nor does it seem to have any Latin roots.

I see etymonline says of obscure origin, which kinda implies knowing more than the full OED's Of unknown origin. But I imagine the reality for both is We haven't got a clue! And I'd be amazed if you get a convincing etymology here given that situation.

...having said that, I believe words often gain/retain currency and/or shift meaning based on sounding similar to other etymologically unrelated words, AND some sounds tend to be associated with areas of meaning independently of vocabulary (not just onomatopoeia). Thinking of words like sprog, sprout, sprod, sprong,... they often seem to relate to "small thing that may have large effect", which seems to be the case with the original "triangular piece of timber" (a small "fillet" of wood helping to align a frame?).

Merriam-Webster is squarely in the “origin unknown” camp.

Does the OP have a reason for thinking there might be an alternative etymology? (Often people post questions because they have a pet theory?)

@FumbleFingers Agreed. I cannot cast any light on the origin, but based on your comments "a small thing that has a large effect" without the small triangular teeth any chain would just slip round the wheel. Also, considering that many gear mechanisms of that era were made of wood, I speculate that the carpenters named the sprocket wheel after the wooden fillet due to the similarity in shape of the teeth.

@PeterJennings: Your take on how to get from that wooden fillet to the "cogged" outer edge of a sprocket wheel looks pretty convincing to me. But I think even for that semantic transition we're only guessing here. Maybe no-one knows how it came to have the original sense, but most likely at least some people know with considerable certainty how the later transition came about.

The carpentry sense is a sticky-outy bit used to create an eave on a roof. It either lands on a plate and supports a rafter outboard of the plate, or it knees off a rafter that lands on a plate and kicks the roof outboard to form an eave.  On smock-type windmills, the cap could be oriented to the wind with several different mechanisms, but basically, sprockets formed a rack, and a pin-gear would wind the cap about the tower. The rack teeth were pretty much the same as eave sprockets. Fantails automated the process.

If the OED is thus far unable to connect sprocket to sprout... whaddya got?

Sprocket -> Etymonline says 'of obscure origin. -- The OED says 'origin unknown' without adding anything else. -- Merriam-Webster is squarely in the “origin unknown” camp. – PaulTanenbaum  in comments. Given the above, any answer will be an opinion (or less charitably, a guess) For that reason I am voting to close.

People (including myself) have answered etymology questions before that the OED and Etymonline couldn't answer. There might be relevant excerpts in some books or other sources. There can be an etymological conjecture also.
